# Flutter bottom Navigation bar with Routes

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-bottomnavigation

I want to navigate through pages using routes and Navigator.pushNamed() on a Bottom Navigation Bar. Here, I'm using a FlashyTab bar for aesthetics. To be more specific, pressing each of the icons on the navigation bar should take me to a different page, and I want to implement this using routes.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Scaffold(
      bottomNavigationBar: FlashyTabBar(
        animationCurve: Curves.linear,
        selectedIndex: _selectedIndex,
        showElevation: true,
        onItemSelected: (index) => setState(() {
          _selectedIndex = index;
        }),
        items: [
          FlashyTabBarItem(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.account_box),
            title: const Text('Challenger'),
          ),
          FlashyTabBarItem(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.phone),
            title: const Text('Contact'),
          ),
          FlashyTabBarItem(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.dashboard_rounded),
            title: const Text('Events'),
          ),
          FlashyTabBarItem(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.badge),
            title: const Text('Quick Scan'),
          ),
        ],
      ),

      body: 

    );
  }
```

Answer (score 10):

In your screen define this

```
List<Widget> pageList = [
    const ChallengerScreen(),
    const ContactScreen(),
    const EventsScreen(),
    const QuickScanScreen(),
  ];
```

In body use it like this

```
return Scaffold(
      bottomNavigationBar: FlashyTabBar(
        animationCurve: Curves.linear,
        selectedIndex: _selectedIndex,
        showElevation: true,
        onItemSelected: (index) => setState(() {
          _selectedIndex = index;
        }),
        items: [
          FlashyTabBarItem(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.account_box),
            title: const Text('Challenger'),
          ),
          FlashyTabBarItem(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.phone),
            title: const Text('Contact'),
          ),
          FlashyTabBarItem(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.dashboard_rounded),
            title: const Text('Events'),
          ),
          FlashyTabBarItem(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.badge),
            title: const Text('Quick Scan'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
//you have to just do changes here...
    body:pageList.elementAt(_selectedIndex)

    );
```

You don't need to use `Navigator.pushNamed()` it not the right method to do.

Comment: My take on the question was "how can I create a history of pages using the navigation bar", not "how do I properly implement the navigation bar" - OP mentions "with routes". Any idea how we can use the navigation bar but push onto routes so users can use the back button/swipe back?

Answer (score 1):

```
bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        items: const [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home),
            label: 'Home',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.route),
            label: 'Water',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.calculate_outlined),
            label: 'Calorie',
          ),
        ],
      ),
```

Comment: Like That how to navigate other routes of dart page in flutter, how to do it with another way.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).